# No notification on successfull Gated Checkin

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, visual-studio-2013

We have TFS2012 and if i check into a branch with CI enabled a gated dialog will appear asking to build (when using both vs2012 and vs2013).

However unlike in vs2012, vs2013 doesn't seem to get a callback to tell it if the checkin was successful.

The Team explorer checkin still shows the details of the checkin (description, associated TFS items) and no dialog pops up to show it was successful like in 2012. Am I missing a configuration step?

Comment: You might have found an actual bug - you can log it here http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio

Comment: raised as bug with Connect https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/807865/

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to configure this in your `Web Portal` of project, you access `Alerts Section` and adjust this by creating `New Alert` based on your check in.

Check your `Administration Console TFS` if it's not resolved, in order to configure your `notification server`.

Comment: I get email alerts ok, its just the "Team Foundation Build Notification" dialog which lives in the windows systray and the team window in vs2013. It works if i checkin to the same project via vs2012 but not via vs2013. The settings you are referring to seem more related to tfs than anything related to either vs2012 or the vs 2013 environment?

Comment: the settings are related to TFS platefrorm so you must access admin console to set theses

Comment: ok so there are settings in the admin console which are relating to vs2013 then? which area in the tfs admin console is it?

Comment: i added  link on image : http://www.google.fr/imgres?sa=X&biw=1517&bih=999&tbm=isch&tbnid=aUGOy0AmyIJuLM:&imgrefurl=http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/de59caa9-fd70-4f8a-947c-4a57d43caee2/tfs-email-alert-for-work-items&docid=dF0MBjuN1lSUgM&imgurl=http://social.microsoft.com/Forums/getfile/48541/&w=977&h=412&ei=QW96Uq6EGoWa1AW94YD4Aw&zoom=1&iact=rc&page=1&tbnh=128&tbnw=304&start=0&ndsp=20&ved=1t:429,r:5,s:0,i:97&tx=67&ty=77

Comment: sorry mate this is the email settings? i am getting email notifications correctly for both vs2012 and vs2013 on my machine for the same project.